# aspnet Membership login control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am building a website that is using the aspnet membership classes.  When the user logs in successfully, I redirect them to a myaccount page.  In this page I want to load a profile, but I need to know what user is logged in.  How would I do this with the aspnet membership stack?

Thanks

Jim Rieck

Answer (score 3):

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 1):

Once a user is logged in to an ASP.NET Forms authenticated page, you can use the [Page.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(VS.80).aspx) property to figure out who they are.

Answer (score 0):

`Context.User.Identity.Name` or `Membership.GetUser();`